# Paper by Y. Amice

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, reference-request

Can anybody help me find the following:
Y. Amice, Duals, Proceedings of a Conference on p-adic Analysis, Nijmegan (1978), 1-15, Math.  Institut Katholische Univ. , 1978

Comment: Same author, same theme, not the same year: http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/GAU/GAU_1973-1974__1_/GAU_1973-1974__1__A3_0/GAU_1973-1974__1__A3_0.pdf

Comment: Dear waller, did you eventually find that article ? I am interested also.

Comment: see https://mathoverflow.net/a/272021/11260 for a scan of Amice's paper