# Nijmegen 1978 $p$-adic analysis proceedings

Tags: reference-request, p-adic-analysis

Anyone knows if there is a chance of getting a copy of the following:

Proceedings of the Conference on p-adic Analysis.
Held in Nijmegen, January 16–20, 1978. Report, 7806. Katholieke Universiteit, Mathematisch Instituut, Nijmegen, 1978. ii+224 pp.

The link to MR is

http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=522116

This book has many interesting articles, in particular, "Duals" of Yvette Amice. I have searched on the internet without results, and I have asked some friends in universities outside Chile if they could get a copy, but it seems very hard. There is a link to Google books, but it has only the "limted search" option.

**Note:** A related question was already asked (in 2011) with no satisfactory answer:

[Paper by Y. Amice](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/51238/paper-by-y-amice)

Comment: You should clarify what you mean you say "it seems very hard," because when I do a multi-library search I see that in the US it is in the libraries at Cornell, IAS, Johns Hopkins, Madison, Michigan, Michigan State, Ohio State, Rutgers, Stanford, Urbana, Yale, and some other places as well.

Comment: @KConrad Yes, of course. It means that there is no copy of the book  in the universities where I have asked. Also, I did not know that there was a multi-library search engine for US libraries. Could you provide a link?. I am not traveling to the US, but I could ask someone when he/she does.

Comment: The multi-library search I did was through my university affiliation, so there is no link I can provide.  But I have given 10+ places where it is, so if you know someone there you can write to them. Although it seems Carlo's answer will be more efficient for your immediate needs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the Nijmegen University Repository I only found pages 193-204, [Non-archimedean differentiation](http://repository.ubn.ru.nl/handle/2066/57030). Since I presume a copy for private use is OK, I have scanned Amice's and Morita's contributions, you can find them here:

- [Duals,
  Yvette Amice](https://ilorentz.org/beenakker/MO/Amice_Nijmegen.pdf)
- [Krasner's
  analytic functions and rigid analytic spaces, Yasuo Morita](https://ilorentz.org/beenakker/MO/Morita_Nijmegen.pdf)

---

*update January 2019:* upon request, I have scanned the entire 224 page volume (58 MB pdf file), available at:

**[Proceedings of the Conference on p-adic analysis](https://ilorentz.org/beenakker/MO/proceedings_1978.pdf) (1978).**

*Note in particular the [list of open problems](https://ilorentz.org/beenakker/MO/proceedings_1978_open_problems.pdf) at the end of the proceedings. How many of these are still open after 40 years?*

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful answer. I would appreciate a lot if you could send me a copy of Amice's paper. My mail is "e_finat AT yahoo DOT com". Also, thank for the link to worldcat. Eugenio.

Comment: I'm also interested in Yasuo Morita, Krasner's analytic functions and rigid analytic spaces (pp. 134–142). Thanks again, Carlo.

Comment: You have made my day, Sir.

Comment: (Maybe, you should also post this as an answer in the question I linked above.)

Comment: Dear Carlo. I'm extremely embarrassed to ask this to you, but is it possible to obtain a copy of Pierrette Cassou-Noguès's article "p-adic L-functions for totally real number field" on the same proceedings? I need it for my research, and I'm still unable to obtain a copy of the full book.

Comment: Thank you very much Carlo.

Comment: Dear Carlo, I really do not know how to thank you. You are extremely genereous with your time and patience :)